How to mock env variables in integration tests (vitest) in Nest.js?
I have this helper function to create application instances for my integration tests:
// create-console.ts
let app: TestingModule | undefined
let bootstrap: TestBootstrapConsole | undefined
let queryRunner: QueryRunner | undefined

export class TestBootstrapConsole extends AbstractBootstrapConsole<TestingModule> {
  public create(): Promise<TestingModule> {
    return Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [this.options.module],
      providers: [queryRunnerProvider],
    })
      .overrideProvider(APPLICATION_LOGGER_TOKEN)
      .useClass(LoggerMock)
      .overrideProvider(DATABASE_LOGGER_TOKEN)
      .useValue(new DatabaseLoggerMock(new LoggerMock()))
      .compile()
  }
}

export const createConsole = async (): Promise<{
  app: TestingModule
  bootstrap: TestBootstrapConsole
  queryRunner: QueryRunner
}> => {
  if (app !== undefined && bootstrap !== undefined && queryRunner !== undefined) {
    return { app, bootstrap, queryRunner }
  }

  bootstrap = new TestBootstrapConsole({
    module: AppModule,
    useDecorators: true,
  })

  app = await bootstrap.init()
  app.useLogger(false)
  await app.init()
  queryRunner = app.get(QUERY_RUNNER)

  if (queryRunner === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`Can't get queryRunner from the testing module app.`)
  }

  return { app, bootstrap, queryRunner }
}

Somewhere along the path I have configs for my envs:
// my.env.ts
export class MyEnv {
  @IsBoolean()
  @Expose()
  @Transform(({ value }) => value === 'true')
  public ENABLE_FREEZE = false
}

// my.config.ts
export class MyConfig {
  public constructor(@Inject(MyEnv) private readonly env: MyEnv) {}

  public get enableFreeze(): boolean {
    return this.env.ENABLE_FREEZE
  }
}

// config.module.ts
@Global()
@Module({
  exports: [
    // ...
    MyConfig,
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
    MyConfig,
  ],
})
export class ConfigModule {}

// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    // ...
    ConfigModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): MiddlewareConsumer | void {
    consumer.apply(contextMiddleware).forRoutes('*')
  }
}

And then I use this code in my test:
const feature = loadFeature('./features/my.feature', {
  loadRelativePath: true,
  tagFilter: 'not @excluded',
})

defineFeature(feature, (test) => {
  let app: TestingModule
  let myConfig: MyConfig

  beforeAll(async () => {
    { app } = await createConsole()
    myConfig = app.get(MyConfig)
    console.log(process.env.ENABLE_FREEZE)
    console.log(myConfig.enableFreeze)
  })

  // ...
})

All the code runs within a docker compose and all values are properly set there:
services:
  application-test:
    environment:
      ENABLE_FREEZE: false

It works fine, and all envs are visible, but I need to mock this ENABLE_FREEZE value for different test cases and for some reason I can't. I've tried:

vi.SpyOn(enableFreeze, 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(true).
vi.mock() with different arguments.
vi.stubEnv('ENABLE_FREEZE', 'true').
To add ENABLE_FREEZE=true in my CLI-command itself.

Literally nothing works. Only after vi.stubEnv(), the process.env.ENABLE_FREEZE returns true, but myConfig.enableFreeze still returns false, no matter in which order I put stub and createConsole() call.
So, how to mock or change ENV variables in vitest integration tests in Nest?
